# Balls and Bins Varaince

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance, balls-in-bins

I am trying to self-learn some statistic concepts and came across this apparently famous "Balls and Bins" Question, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

So suppose we have 5 balls and 12 bins and *each ball is * equally likely to land in any bin.

Let there be some random variable $X_{i}$ denoting the number of balls in bin *i*.

We have to find the variance of $X_{1}+X_{2}...+X_{12}$

My half baked take is that we can try finding the expected value of $X_{i}$ and go from there. I assume, probably incorrectly, that the expected load on each bin would be $$\frac{5}{12}$$

I don't know if my computation is correct, or where to go from here even if it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It's a trick question. The sum

$$ X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{12} $$

is always exactly 5, for every outcome. So the variance is zero.

Comment: Oh I feel so stupid, enough to delete my post ‍♂️

Comment: +1 As a generalisation, if $n$ balls go into $m$ bins each independently with uniform distribution then the sum of the counts $X_1+X_2+\cdots+ X_k$ with $1\le k \le m$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $\frac{k}{m}$, so expectation $n\frac{k}{m}$ and variance $n \frac{k}{m}\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)$.  When $k=m$ the expectation is $n$ and variance is $0$.